# Can't change unshared_at over API request

Tags: shared, box-api

I've spent hour trying to make it work without any luck.

Here is my request:

```
curl "https://www.box.com/api/2.0/files/16914859603" -H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" -XPUT -d'{"shared_link":{"unshared_at":"2014-05-28T23:59:00-07:00"}}'
```

Here is response from server:

```
{
    "type":"error",
    "status":400,
    "code":"bad_request",
    "context_info":{
         "errors":[{
             "reason":"invalid_parameter",
             "name":"unshared_at",
             "message":"Invalid value '1401346740'."}
         ]},
         "help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors",
         "message":"Bad Request","request_id":"2012234400537b5f6725fab"
     }
```

I've tried to use different variations of date and time like:

- 2014-05-28T23:59:00-07:00
- 2014-05-28 23:59:00
- 2014-05-28
- 1400594580

Comment: Are you a paying customer? The API documentation indicates that the `unshared_at` feature is not available to 'free' users. Could that be the problem?

Comment: That was fixed by contacting box.com support. Not sure where was the problem, I think I had a wrong account type which they updated manually.